# Can I migrate a VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest to a *real* Hardware Box?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to transfer Ubuntu from a VirtualBox Guest 'appliance' to a **real** (metal and chips) computer?

Can this be done, and what steps are involved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd try it with `dd` (don't forget to replace the device names like `sda` with your device name):

1. Replace all uuids in your `/etc/fstab` with things like `/dev/sda1` (`sda` = destination hd number!)
2. `update-grub2 && grub-install /dev/sda`
3. Save your virtual hdd inside VBox into a File: `dd if=/dev/sda /home/user/sda.img`
4. Copy the Image to a disk (external hdd, network share, dvd, ...)
5. Restore the Image to the destination drive: `dd if=/media/drive/sda.img of=/dev/sda`

The biggest problem might be the bootloader (but there are tutorials for this even in this forum). I once reinstalled a bootloader by doing a fresh install of Ubuntu (preferably the same as the one you dd'ed) and then `dd` the old partition over the fresh install (in this case, you would only `dd` `/dev/sda1`, not `/dev/sda`, which also includes the bootloader and all partitions)

Comment: I can handle dd. I've used it before and know the **if** isn't the start of a conditional statement :) ... For some reason uuids and grub baffle me.. They are probably quite simple, but then again I might be too.. I'll probably use the MBR from a fresh (dummy) install.. The biggest hurdle for me is to actually dd the partitons from the VM..  How can I dd from a VM partition to the Host?

Comment: ... a bit more (I tried to edit this into my previous comment, but the edit was disallowed!?.. another minor mystery): . . .   VirtualBox's shared folders seem to rely on the Addons which aren't present in a Live-CD run, because it requires a reboot.

Comment: you could dd to a network folder, I did this last week and it was like 30MB/s. If you set a shared folder in your live-cd environment/windows/linux and activate bridged network for the VM this should work.

Comment: btw: it's possible to copy an entire Linux-Partition with cp (+ some arguments to keep the permissoins! Very important! I think it was -p or --preserve=all). I did this once to copy back an image after resizing a partition (so I mounted the dd-Image file and did cp)

Comment: Sorry to be so dumb about this, but I must be missing some incredibly simple point... Everything I read seems to imply that NAT allows the Guest to access the Host by **default** (a connection in the other direction needs Bridging).. Okay I've had my three guesses (more like thirty!). I've successfully accessed VBox's Shared Folders **only** when Guest Addons are installed. I can't install these Addons in a LiveCD run, so I'm stuck again. How do I access the NAT connected Host's file sysem from the Guest (no Addons)? I suppose I need to do something on the host, but I don't knwow what it is?

Comment: you could also install Ubuntu on a second disk, then install everything as you want (vbox etc.), then dd the hdd of the other vm with this installation.

Comment: Yes, thanks.. but for this **adventure** I want to work on both systems at the same time.. My *live* version, and a "VM version which I will slowly rebuild to be the same as my current one, but without the dross I've generated along the way..... I think I finally solve my "major" simple problem: To share a folder on the network, I first have to **click the share button** in Nautialus.. Duuurrrr! :)  I think this nut is now cracked!... and yes, as you indicated, dd is fast: I clicked 107 MB/s while writing 0's to a Sata drive, and I don't have the latest hardware, let alone solid state drives.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried [this](http://blog.chris-alex-thomas.com/2009/03/17/migrate-virtualboxlinux-to-a-native-machine/) myself, but description seems to be realistic enough to try.

Comment: The article you mention is on a similar path to where I want to go. If I ignore his Fedora LVM issues, it **almost** resolves one of my problems: How to get the VM partion into the Host environmnet. He mentions a VirualBox tool **VBoxManage** which emables the mounting of a raw VM disk image on the Host. However there is a problem with this article insomuch as it relates to a Windows Host. The **command-name** is okay, but none of the args are recognized...  but I assume the same is available for Linux... Does someone know the syntax?

Comment: Try running "VBoxManage internalcommands" - it prints out some usage information. Might appear to be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

1> do a tar of your virtualBox OS

2> start with a live distro

3> untar your virtualBox OS in the target partition/s (/dev/sda1 for example)

4> make the partition bootable (fdisk can help you):
   # fdisk /dev/sda
   Command (m for help): a   (a = toggle a bootable flag)
   Partition number (1-4): 1 (1 = /dev/sda1)
   Command (m for help): q   (q = exit)

5> install grub into mbr (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2)
   # mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
   # mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   # mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   # mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   # cd /mnt && chroot .
   #(chroot) update-grub
   #(chroot) grub-install /dev/sda (NOT /dev/sda1!)
   #(chroot) grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX

6> Enjoy...

Comment: To **tar** my VirtualBox OS sounds so easy... but not for me... For example; Where do I tar it to?  I assume that the appropriate way to **tar** a file system is to not have it in use... so I booted the VM via a LiveCD...  This gave me access to the VM's drive via the LiveCD's /media.... but how do I get the data out of the VM.. VirtualBox's Shared Folders requires the GuestAddons, which requires a reboot, which restart the Live CD to its no-Addons state...  Or have I missed something about VirtualBox's Shared Folders/

Comment: You can tar (rsync also) the system directly even if it's running (this is Linux...):

Comment: You can tar the system directly even if it's running. This is Linux ;-).
First install this packages: sshfs (http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.htm) and mount a real directory inside virtualbox.
For example you can use,inside virtualbox as I said, a pendrive (mounted, let me say, in /media/pendrive) in this way:
# sshfs root@10.0.2.2:/media/pendrive /mnt

After tar directly from your RUNNING virtualbox to the pendrive (Linux can):
# cd /
# tar -cvpzf /mnt/backup.tgz --exclude=/proc/ --exclude=/lost+found/ --exclude=/mnt/ --exclude=/sys/ /

Answer (score 1):

What exactly from the install do you want to migrate?  If all you care about are user data and preferences, you could probably just copy everything from your home directory on the VM to a file system outside the VM (a keydrive, for example), copy those files over to a fresh Ubuntu install and then reinstall any programs you had installed on the VM.  Depends on how much you've customized the VM install, versus how much trouble the other solutions here would be.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu (first time Linux user) on real hardware.  I've been learning a **lot**, but my system has gathered a lot of clutter. I've tweaked one setting and forgotten where I set it, etc.  My idea is to use the (minimal) experience I now have, and build a parallel VM system, without the mistakes, and then just shuffle it across to the primary hardware. I can take my time about it and still experiment on the current one. Its also a good "learning" project...  but I'm feeling like I've bitten off a bit more than I can chew :)  ... getting there slowly...

Answer (score 1):

I like to use rsync for backing up my system. This is good for a home directroy or ect directory but might not be what you're looking for in terms of a complete system migration. To use rsync, you'll need to install ubuntu on both systems. Update both of them so that the packages are the same and are at the same level (this isn't mandatory but does make things easier). Then, to copy your home dir from server1 to server2 you can run the following on server1:

```
$rsync -avz /home/username/ username@server2:/home/username/
```

The thing that I like about this is that rsync will calculate the differences between directories and transfer the changes rather than everything. This way you can keep your backup current by running on server2 (to backup on server1):

```
$rsync -avz /home/username/ username@server1:/home/username/
```

hth

Comment: Thanks, I've been using rsync to backup my non-OS partitions (ie.. data, like music, etc). I too like the way rsync works; very efficient.  My main "problem" is that I don't know if a simple file copy from the VM to equivalent partitions will work. Eg. How will Ubuntu handle the different HARDWARE. Does it automatically detect it and adjust on bootup? Windows certainly wouldn't! and I'm not yet sure how to handle mount points: I don't want to rsync my TeraByte drive across to the OS partition; and GRUB spins me out. These are the little fun things I don't quite know enough about yet..