# How can I migrate a *real* hardware box to a singularity docker?

Tags: 18.04, docker

This is kind of the opposite of this question here: [Can I migrate a VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest to a *real* Hardware Box?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8471/can-i-migrate-a-virtualbox-ubuntu-guest-to-a-real-hardware-box#8476)

I want to enable other people to use the exact same OS and package versions I have used to be able to execute my code under identical conditions...

I guess I have to create a system image of my real machine (Ubuntu 18.04) and install that one a singularity docker, but am stuck on the details.
I know how to manually create a singularity docker running ubuntu and detailed package versions, but I want to just copy my system to a docker to avoid forgetting certain packages and dependencies...

Is this possible, and how?

Any input or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way of getting that done AFAIK.

The brute-force approach would be to backup /etc/ directory contents (and any others that are in use, like /opt/ etc.) for reference and to export you repo and package lists etc. same as you might when installing a new machine.

But perhaps you should look at setting up an automation tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works) on the original machine, and then you can apply the process to the docker system. It requires work to setup, but once done you can easily automate pushes to any future systems?

Comment: SO basically, brute force would be sth like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallingSamePackages ?

Comment: Ha, indeed, that would be the brute force approach. It's simple, though, and you'll get most of the way there, which may be good enough for your needs!